# Common LISP: convert (unknown) struct object to plist?

Tags: common-lisp

```
(defstruct (mydate (:constructor make-mydate (year month day)))
  (year 1970)
  (month 1)
  (day 1))

 (defvar *date1* (make-mydate 1992 1 1))
```

The problem is more general, but say I would like to convert an object like *date1* to a "document" I can persist to a database (e.g. mongoDB, using package cl-mongo). So I write

```
(defun mydate->document (mydate)
   (cl-mongo:$ (cl-mongo:$ "year" (mydate-year mydate))
               (cl-mongo:$ "month" (mydate-month mydate))
               (cl-mongo:$ "day" (mydate-day mydate))))

REPL--> (mydate->doc *date1*)
kv-container : #(#S(CL-MONGO::PAIR :KEY year :VALUE 1992)
                 #S(CL-MONGO::PAIR :KEY month :VALUE 1)
                 #S(CL-MONGO::PAIR :KEY day :VALUE 1))
```

But could I, instead of having to write down all fields of my struct, obtained their names and values programmatically? After all, my lisp runtime can do that:

```
REPL--> (describe *date1*)
#S(MYDATE :YEAR 1992 :MONTH 1 :DAY 1)
  [structure-object]

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
YEAR   = 1992
MONTH  = 1
DAY    = 1
```

On the other hand, I did not find anything relevant in any book, and I noticed that the library cl-json cannot convert structs to JSON format (even though it does convert lists and CLOS objects). I guess that if there was a function to convert a struct to a plist, the problem would be solved.

Comment: A defstruct defines a class; so you can use class-slots. Or you can define it to use a list or vector backing. Or, potentially just use Print …

Comment: @BRPocock defstruct class-slots is not defined for structures in the language standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no portable way.

Implementations do it differently. Probably most have a way to access the names of the slots. It's not clear to me why such functionality is missing from the standard.

LispWorks for example has:

```
(structure:structure-class-slot-names (find-class 'some-structure-class))
```

Maybe there is already a compatibility library somewhere. It would make sense to use the Meta-Object Protocol functionality for CLOS also for structure classes.

SBCL:

```
* (sb-mop:class-slots (find-class 'foo))

(#<SB-PCL::STRUCTURE-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION A>
 #<SB-PCL::STRUCTURE-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION B>)

* (mapcar 'sb-mop:slot-definition-name *)

(A B)
```

Comment: A quick follow-up question, if you would, @RainerJoswig ? I thought that the MOP necessarily applied to DEFSTRUCT objects; does your answer imply that the `class-slots` should necessarily work everywhere (via e.g. `closer-mop`)?

Comment: @BRPocock  Since the MOP is not a part of standard CL, it is not required in Common Lisp implementations. CLASS-SLOTS is by the MOP also only usefully defined for standard-class.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called [Meta-Object Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaobject#Metaobject_protocol).
[Common lisp pioneered MOP](http://mop.lisp.se/), but only for CLOS objects, not for `defstruct` objects.
Some CL implementations support [`defstruct` MOP](http://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/port/mop.lisp), but not all of them, you can check that using:

```
(defstruct s a)
(slot-definition-initargs (car (class-direct-slots (find-class 's))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is SBCL specific:

In REPL is can do this:

```
(struct-to-list '(NIL #S(N :V 78) #S(OP :V #\*)
 #S(E :V1 #S(N :V 456) :OP #S(OP :V #\+) :V2 #S(N :V 123))))
```

which will give this result =>

```
(NIL
 ((N (V 78))
  ((OP (V #\*)) ((E (V1 (N (V 456))) (OP (OP (V #\+))) (V2 (N (V 123)))) NIL))))
```

The code used:

```
(defun struct-names (struct)
  (loop for sl in (sb-mop::class-direct-slots (class-of struct))
        collect (list
                 (sb-mop:slot-definition-name sl)
                 (slot-value sl 'sb-pcl::internal-reader-function))))

(defun struct-values (struct)
  (cons (type-of struct)
        (loop for np in (struct-names struct)
              collect (cons (car np)
                            (funcall (cadr np) struct)))))

(defun structp (val)
  (equalp 'STRUCTURE-OBJECT
          (sb-mop:class-name (car (sb-mop:class-direct-superclasses (class-of val))))))

(defun struct-to-list (val)
  (cond
    ((structp val)
     (loop for v in (struct-values val)
           collect (struct-to-list v)))
    ((consp val)
     (cons (struct-to-list (car val))
           (struct-to-list (cdr val))))
    (T val)))
```