# using a struct as property list to macro

Tags: common-lisp

I have a struct with `:name` and `:value` that I'd like to use as arguments to a macro. But I'm not sure how to tell lisp that.

I can write out the call like

```
(sxql:yield (sxql:set= :name "a" :value 1))
```

> "SET name = ?, value = ?"
>
> ("a" 1)

But I'd like to use an already existing structure

```
(defstruct my-struct name value)
(setq x (make-my-struct :name "a" :value 1))
; #S(MY-STRUCT :NAME "a" :VALUE 1)
```

using answers from [Common LISP: convert (unknown) struct object to plist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084260/common-lisp-convert-unknown-struct-object-to-plist)
I've made

```
(defun struct-plist (x)
  "make struct X into a property list. ugly kludge"
  (let* ((slots (sb-mop:class-slots (class-of x)))
     (names (mapcar 'sb-mop:slot-definition-name slots)))
    (alexandria:flatten
     (mapcar (lambda (n) (list (intern (string n) "KEYWORD")
                   (slot-value x n)))
         names))))
```

```
(setq p (struct-plist x)) ; (:NAME "a" :VALUE 1)
```

My naive attempts are

```
(sxql:set= p) ; error in FORMAT: No more argument SET ~{~A = ~A~^, ~}
(funcall 'sxql:set= p) ; SXQL:SET= is a macro, not a function.
(macroexpand (sxql:set= p)) ; error in FORMAT ...
```

I imagine this is an easy/fundamental lisp programming question. But I'm not sure how to ask it (or search for answers). I'm also hoping there is an better struct<->plist story than what I've stumbled across so far.

EDIT: In case this is really an xy-problem. I've used `flydata:defmodel` to create the struct and I want to insert to a database using the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely an xy problem: unfortunately I don't understand y (flydata?) well enough to answer the y part.

Here's why what you are trying to do can't work however.  Consider this code in a file being compiled:

```
(defstruct mine name value)

...

(sxql:set= <anything derived from mine>)
```

Compiling this file must satisfy two constraints:

1. It does *not* fully create the structure type `mine` (see [defstruct](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm));
2. It must macroexpand `sxql:set=`.

What these constraints mean is that `sxql:set=` *can't know about the structure* at the time it is expanded.  So any trick which relies on information about the structure must make that information available at compile time.

As I said, I don't understand the y part well enough to understand what you are trying to do, but a hacky approach to this is:

- write a wrapper for `defstruct` which stashes information at compile time (strictly: at macro-expansion time);
- write a wrapper for `sxql:set=` which uses that information to expand into something which makes sense.

Here is a mindless wrapper for `defstruct`.  Note that this is *mindless*: it can only understand the most simple `defstruct` forms, and even then it may be wrong.  It exists only as an example.

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defvar *structure-information* '()))
  
(defmacro define-mindless-structure (name &body slots)
  (assert (and (symbolp name)
               (every #'symbolp slots))
      (name slots)
    "I am too mindless")
  (let ((found (or (assoc name *structure-information*)
                   (car (push (list name) *structure-information*)))))
    (setf (cdr found) (mapcar (lambda (slot)
                                (list slot (intern (symbol-name slot)
                                                   (find-package "KEYWORD"))
                                      (intern (concatenate 'string
                                                           (symbol-name name)
                                                           "-"
                                                           (symbol-name slot)))))
                              slots)))
  `(defstruct ,name ,@slots))
```

So now

```
(define-mindless-structure mine
  name value)
```

Will expand into `(defstruct mine name value)` and, *at macroexpansion time* will stash some information about this structure in `*structure-information*`.

Now I stop really understanding what you need to do because I don't know what `sxql:set=` is meant to do, but it might be something like this:

```
(defmacro mindless-set= ((s o))
  (let ((info (assoc s *structure-information*))
        (ov (make-symbol "O")))
    (unless info
      (error "no information for ~A" s))
    `(let ((,ov ,o))
       (sxql:set= ,@(loop for (slot initarg accessor) in (cdr info)
                          ;; the compiler will whine about slot annoyingly
                          collect initarg
                          collect `(,accessor ,ov))))))
```

So with this macro, assuming a suitable `define-mindless-structure` for `mine` form has been seen by the time the macro is expanded, then

```
(mindless-set= (mine it))
```

Will expand into

```
(let ((#:o it))
  (set= :name (mine-name #:o) :value (mine-value #:o)))
```

But, as I said, I am not sure what the expansion you actually want is.

---

Finally, before even thinking about using anything like the above, it would be worth looking around to see if there are portability libraries which provide compile/macroexpansion-time functionality like this: there very well may be such, as I don't keep up with things.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The didactic `define-mindless-structure` is super helpful

Comment: @Will: yes, 'didactic' is the term I should have used: I'm glad you realised it was.  It's not industrial-strength but it might help I hope.